# Infineon TLE9879 Cortex M3 reset behavior

Tags: embedded, hardware, microcontroller, reset, infineon

I'm developing for a custom embedded board having an Infineon TLE9879 which is a motor controller containing an ARM Cortex-M3 programmable core. My code runs fine from flash with the debugger attached, but when I disconnect it to run the product stand-alone I get nothing. We have an evaluation board up and running with the same code, so my first thought was something different in the hardware. The eval board has an extra chip for the JTAG interface, so it's not really possible to run it the same way. The eval board does run stand-alone if I unplug the USB cable but there is still extra hardware connected on the board that is not present in our product. The connections on our JTAG appear to match the recommendations, and I am able to make it work with connected to the IDE.

Is there anything internal to the chip that may need to be configured when programming that might be set incorrectly? Any other ideas? This feels like a missing pull-up or misconfigured bit preventing it from getting out of reset.

update: It actually work stand-alone sometimes, but usually does not. It does seem to be running, as we have a PWM output to indicate status and that is running even if nothing else works. I will try to hack the code to get a more meaningful status out the PWM. I'm still confused as to why it would always run fine with the debugger attached and hardly ever without it.

Comment: start simple, go back to blinking an led...and work your way forward.

Comment: Difficult to say, a schematic and some source might help. In any event skimming the datasheet for the MCU I don't see an internal pull-up mentioned on the reset line whereas the evaluation board has that programming interface, so perhaps you might double-check that it isn't floating.

Comment: In addition to the reset you might check any boot mode pins that determine if execution starts from flash vs. RAM.  Also if you had full jtag rather than SWD make sure all those lines are at levels consistent with ordinary operation.  I'm assuming your motor isn't connected, but obviously if it were it noise issues would be suspect, granted more so operationally than at startup.  You might also try manually pulsing the reset a few seconds after power on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming, but hardware design. (Or it involves it)

Comment: This is not necessarily a hardware issue at all. To the OP, what IDE are you using to write your code? In Crossworks you have to ensure STARTUP_FROM_RESET is defined in your project. If it is not, you will see exactly this behaviour.